# How could I pass a parameter within the javascript function called from jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I'm having a `jsp` page which displays a grid, containing data from the database. For each and every record I'm having an action called `editRecord()` which is a button in the jsp page. I'm having the `editRecord` function within a separate `javascript` file which has `id`(id of the record) as the parameter.

What I need to know is, if I'm having something like this in my jsp for my button:

```
<button id="reviewEdit" type="button" 
    class="edit-btn pull-right margin-left10 recos"
    onclick="editPersonalDetail()">

    <span class="fa fa-edit margin-right3"></span>
    <fmt:message key="review.grid.btn.edit"/>
</button>
```

How should I pass the record id as the parameter within the `onclick` function? If needed can post the function as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In a JSP you can just simply print the variable as a literal:

```
editPersonalDetail(<%=record.getId()%>);
```

This is a JSP expression shorthand, do not confuse it with scriptlets (which are *bad*). Of course, the code inside the JSP block will be different.

You can also use the JSTL `c:out`:

```
editPersonalDetail(<c:out value="record.id"/>);
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is you can pass the value for your record id as:

```
 onclick="editPersonalDetail('"+ <%= your_jsp_variable %> +"')"
```

The other way you can use JSTL library.

Comment: You do not need concatenation and double quotes (it won't even work this way).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do it through javascript.

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
    var $text = $row.find(".nr").text(); // Find the text

    // Let's test it out
    alert($text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/1264/

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to keep variables in hidden inputs. 
So in jsp you have this:

```
<input id='record_id' type='hidden' value='<%= record.getId() %>' />
```

and in javascript you get it like this:

```
var record_id = document.getElementById("record_id").value;
```

or use jQuery:

```
var record_id = $("#record_id").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the value that is present in the model, then you could try this..

onclick="editPersonalDetail(' + modelname.columnname +')"

check whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSTL.

```
<button id="reviewEdit" type="button" 
    class="edit-btn pull-right margin-left10 recos"
    onclick="editPersonalDetail('<c:out value="${record.id}"/>')">

    <span class="fa fa-edit margin-right3"></span>
    <fmt:message key="review.grid.btn.edit"/>
</button>
```